# How to access text file in Maven Project using ClassPathResource in Java?

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to access file "raw_sentences.txt" file using "ClassPathResource" in Maven java project. My file is located in the "\src\main\resources\com\thesis\work\raw_sentences.txt". I have tried many ways but it always returning with an error NullPointerExcepetion. I can access the file from

> File testf = new File( obj.getClass().getResource( "raw_sentences.txt" ).toURI() );

But ClassPathResrouce is not working i don't know why, please help!

```
package com.thesis.work;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

public class App 
{
static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");  

public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException, URISyntaxException
{   
    App obj = new App();
    File testf = new File( obj.getClass().getResource( "raw_sentences.txt" ).toURI() );
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "File: ", testf.getPath()); // Works!

    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Load data...\n");
    ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("raw_sentences.txt");
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "File loaded : ", resource.getPath()); // not Working!
}

static void print(String nd){
    System.out.println(nd);
}}
```

> `Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [raw_sentences.txt] cannot be opened because it does not exist
>       at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157)
>       at com.thesis.work.App.main(App.java:24)`

[image: Here is the structure of Maven project directory]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("com/thesis/work/raw_sentences.txt");`

Comment: Thanks, actually i haven't work with maven projects. Can i do this by using only the file name?

Answer (score 0):

They both shall be right.

Suppose there is the `java` file `com/a/b/App.java`, and the resource directory is `com/a/b/test.test`.

Then,

both

```
ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("/com/a/b/test.dat");
```

and

```
ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("test.dat");
```

should be fine.

The deep reason is that, `maven` would copy the contents of resource to `target/classes/`.

Therefore, the `test.dat` is in the same directory with `App.class`, and `test.dat` or `/com/a/b/test.dat` both are right.

Here is the file structure in `target`:

```
  target
    |__
     classes
        └── a
            └── b
                |__
                   test.dat
                   App.class
```

Comment: It is not like this in my case, ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("com/thesis/work/raw_sentences.txt"); //Works!
        ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("raw_sentences.txt");//Not Working